# Same server name in VPN

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, vpn

My .NET solution must be accessible from some **http://customservername.com** URL and it has this line as a starting URL in all project's properties. What i did to run it under my local PC is made a virtual web folder named **customservername.com** and wrote **"127.0.0.1 customservername.com"** line in the hosts file. The database for the site is placed in other network that i can connect to using VPN, so i need to VPN to make the site work well.
However, i get "unable to start debugging on web server..." error when starting the solution. If i dont connect to VPN then all runs well, but the DB is not accessible.
I've found out that remote network has **customservername.com** working host and that gave me an idea that VS somehow tries to publish solution there. Why it's so? I do have the line in "hosts". How should i solve the trouble? Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: When you start the VPN and then ping customservername.com, which IP address does it ping?

Comment: Ok good, what version of IIS is it, or are you talking about Cassini?